# Question on AP(sequences and series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that sqrt(2), sqrt(3) and sqrt(5) cannot be terms of an A.P.(not necessarily consecutive)!

Answer (score 2):

Assume that they can be in A.P.

$\sqrt{2}+(n-1)d=\sqrt{3}$
$\sqrt{2}+(m-1)d=\sqrt{5}$
$m$, $n$ are natural numbers.

$\Longrightarrow$ $~$ $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{n-1}{m-1}$

LHS is irrational and RHS is rational, which is contradiction.
Hence, they cannot be in A.P.

Answer (score 0):

If there are terms of an A.P. then $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}$ is rational (why?). Therefore $$\sqrt{3}(m+n)=\sqrt{5}n+\sqrt{2}m$$
for some $n,m\in\mathbb N.$
Contradiction (Why?).